# Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm new to AWS Amplify, and have created a GraphQL API for a project that I'm working on in order to learn it & AppSync. Essentially I have a schema that looks like the following:

```
type User @model {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  boards: [Board] @hasMany
  createdAt: String!
  updatedAt: String!
}

type Board @model {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  createdBy: User!
  title: String!
}
```

and I'm trying to run the following query in the AppSync console:

```
query MyQuery {
  listUsers {
    items {
      boards {
        items {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But for some reason I keep seeing this error:

```
Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes: Primary key attribute: userBoardsId
```

I've specified the primary key in both models, and I'm aware that AppSync generates the 'userBoardsId' foreign key, but I'm not sure why it's causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried like this? Since boards is array, you need to add `items`

```
query MyQuery {
  listUsers {
    items {
      boards {
        items {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**:

```
type User @model {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  boards: [Board] @hasMany (indexName: "byUser")
  createdAt: String!
  updatedAt: String!
}
```

```
type Board @model {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  userID: ID! @index(name: "byUser")
  createdBy: User
  title: String!
}
```

Comment: Oh, my bad. I have tried it, and still receive the same error. I'll update my question to have the more correct query in it!

Comment: @RundownDuck, I see, I've edited my answer, can you try using that schema. I haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: Yup that works!